# How to show 2 markers in google map to differentiate origin and destination if destination is very nearby to origin?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]I developed google api for finding route between 2 places ... but when origin and destination is very nearby the marker used for destination is only visible i.e [Marker B] ... the marker for origin [Marker A] hides behind the destination [Marker B] ... i need origin [Marker A] should be slightly visible out of destination [Marker B] ... Look out the sample image i enclosed, only Marker B is visible ... need Marker A should also be visible ... is it possible ? What changes should be done in the following code ?

```
var myOptions = 
{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(default_latitude,default_longitude),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapp"),myOptions);

var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(glat,glon);

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("panel"));
var request = {
  origin: acity,
  destination:latlng,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
}); 
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add the suppressMarkers:true option to the [DirectionRenderer options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)
2. add your icons, make the [zIndex of the "start" marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) bigger than the zIndex of the end marker.

Comment: suppressMarkers make the markers to be invisible .... i need markers there in map ... but wanna make both A & B visisble

Comment: oh ok ok .... actually i dont hav a marker variable ... those markers are auto generated by directionsrenderer ... can u pls send me a sample code for this so that i can understand easily ...

Comment: Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html) with custom start and end markers.  It is more complicated than you need (it renders the whole route), but you can just use the start/end marker code.  It also doesn't make sure the start marker has a higher zIndex than the end marker.